# Resize NITF while maintaining metadata

Tags: python, gdal, metadata, nitf

What I want to do: I'm working on enhancing a legacy NITF reader in C++. Before I touch it, I want to create a battery of unit tests to make sure I don't break things while I'm trying to improve them. I want to create my unit tests around several example NITFs that I've been given. Naturally, the NITFs are too big to fit into the repo with the unit tests, and so I want to shrink the size of the NITFs while maintaining the metadata (the metadata is most important. Only the number of bands and the pixel data type is important to me right now.). My NITFs are not projected if that helps. Basically, I want to create a directory of test NITFs that contain the metadata of the originals but are just a few pixels or so kind of like in the GDAL repo [here](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/tree/master/autotest/gdrivers/data/nitf).

What I've tried: I started using gdalwarp to make the image smaller, but it seems to strip the metadata. I've tried a few other things but I've had most success with using GDAL create with the python bindings to create 2x2 NITFs and use the options parameter to copy over the TREs. But there are other little tidbits, namely the NITF_METDATA fields, that I can't figure out how to copy to the newly created NITFs. I've tried using the creation options but I get an error that the NITF driver doesn't support that key, which maybe I'm using the wrong one, and I've tried using ds.SetMetadata, which returns 0 but doesn't seem to change the metadata fields of the output NITF. I've poked around the gdal unit tests for an example, but I can't seem to find one.

Here's a rough example of my latest iteration:

```
ds_original = gdal.Open(original_nitf_path, gdalconst.GA_ReadOnly)
bands = ds_original.RasterCount
dtype = ds_original.GetRasterBand(1).DataType
xsize = 2
ysize = 2

tre = ds_original.GetMetadata("TRE")
tre_options = [f'TRE={key}={tre[key]}' for key in tre.keys()]

ds_test = gdal.GetDriverByName('NITF').Create(
    test_nitf_path,
    xsize, ysize, bands, dtype,
    options=["ICORDS=D"] + tre_options
)

for key, value in ds_original.GetMetadata("NITF_METADATA").items():
    ds_test.SetMetadata(f'{key}={value}')

ds_test = None
```

Per the accepted answer, the code above should look a little more like the code below in that the metadata fields should be set in the creation options without the `NITF_` part. Some of the metadata fields below aren't supported (so the code below isn't 100% correct), but this is more the correct idea.

```
ds_original = gdal.Open(original_nitf_path, gdalconst.GA_ReadOnly)
bands = ds_original.RasterCount
dtype = ds_original.GetRasterBand(1).DataType
xsize = 2
ysize = 2

tre = ds_original.GetMetadata("TRE")
tre_options = [f'TRE={key}={tre[key]}' for key in tre.keys()]
metadata = ds_original.GetMetadata()
metadata_options = [f"{key.removeprefix('NITF_')}={val}" for key, val in metadata.items()]

ds_test = gdal.GetDriverByName('NITF').Create(
    test_nitf_path,
    xsize, ysize, bands, dtype,
    options=tre_options + metadata_options
)

ds_test = None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of what gets reported as `NITF_METADATA` is really fields from the image segment subheader. The GDAL [help page for NITF](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/nitf.html) says:

> Most file header, imagery header metadata and security fields can be set with appropriate creation options (although they are reported as metadata item, but must not be set as metadata).

So you need to set creation options. Not metadata. And don't put the `NITF_` part in.

Not all of them will make sense, so check the [list of valid options](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/nitf.html#creation-issues). For example, the NROWS and NCOLS are from the number of pixels, not from a NITF creation option.

That said, I'm going to suggest re-evaluating your approach. Just borrow the resources from https://github.com/codice/imaging-nitf/tree/master/shared-test-resources as a git submodule. Reasons:

- using GDAL to rewrite the files will mean you're checking GDAL outputs, not the weird variations in the originals, which is probably useful.
- you'll get a bit wider range of TREs, and you can use those to build real unit tests (like just one feature), rather than trying to work on file-at-once.
- some TREs won't make sense without the original data dimensions (no ICHIPB, etc) when you get to making sense of the results

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response with links. I appreciate your time. What specifically helped was the tip to use creation options and omitting the `NITF_` part, and the link the to the valid creation options (I needed `ISUBCAT` for one of the images). And thanks for the gentle suggestion to leverage GDAL's test resources. I'll give that some thought. I'm still getting my arms around what the code is doing and the weird variations in the images we're provided with - and thus still figuring out the testing requirements. Thanks again.

Comment: If you haven't already seen them, the Spectral NITF Implementation Profile ("SNIP") team put together a great set of reference implementation products, including a large collection of ISUBCAT in some of the segments. You can download them from the NSG registry in different ways - probably the easiest is https://nsgreg.nga.mil/doc/view?i=5523 (no direct link, because it expires)

Comment: I have not seen this. Thanks for the follow up. I'll look into it.